# Are the creatures in the Never Seen That Before Achievement randomly throughout the world?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

There is a massive list of monsters to kill for this achievement.  Are these rare monster  spawns completely random in the world or are there set locations that I should look?  If so, has anyone compiled a list?

*[Side note: I noticed this achievement when my buddy got it in Co-OP and I did not - As I was not by him at the time.  Be sure to be near your co-op buddy when you down the rare]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. These monsters only appear in certain areas, but they are not guaranteed to appear every time.

Most of the otherwise non-randomoverworld has this - non-random terrain, with randomization variables; monsters and dungeons that may or may not appear.

Comment: Are specific monsters only in specific acts?

Comment: Yup. I'd recommend one of the wikis for a "who's who".